# Javascript filtering/includes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an array of IDs and an array of objects with IDs. I need to filter out all the objects that have an ID equal to any ID in the ID array..

I've tried some combinations of .filter, .includes & .forEach functions but can't seem to think my way out of this one.

```
const a = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
const b = [2, 3]


const c = a.filter((item) => item.id !== b.forEach((item))

//desired result
console.log(c)   //this should log [{id: 1}]
```

Comment: How is the output {id:1} as it is not present in b?

Comment: Do you want an array of ids which are in both the arrays?

Comment: _"I need to filter out ..."_ <-- so he only wants those that aren't in `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Array.includes`

```js
const a = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
const b = [2, 3]

const c = a.filter((item) => !b.includes(item.id))

//desired result
console.log(c)   //this should log [{id: 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would solve your problem:

```
const a = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
const b = [2, 3]


const c = a.filter((item) => !b.includes(item.id))


console.log(c)
```